# consolidate multiple sheets into two master sheets

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have a workbook with 15 sheets for different business lines.

This workbook is a template with multiple empty rows on each sheet.

I would like to consolidate sheets 1, 4, 7, 10, and 13 into a master sheet that adds only rows that are not empty.

In addition, I would like to consolidate sheets 2, 5, 8, 11, and 14 into a master sheet that adds only rows that are not empty.

I believe this can be done with VBA, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Good question. I left out that I use Excel for Mac

Comment: If you download an [ODBC driver](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/ODBC-drivers-that-are-compatible-with-Excel-for-Mac-9FA6BC7F-D19E-4F7F-9BE4-92E85C77D712) for Mac Excel, you can run SQL queries on workbooks, specifically union queries with `WHERE` clauses to filter out empty row.

Answer (score 0):

The following is only a part of your issue.

This code use filter to eliminate blanks on the first column and copy the data on a new sheet.

```
Sub SelectNonBlankAndPasteonNewSheet()

    Cells.Select
    Selection.AutoFilter

    With Selection

        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>"
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy

     End With

    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```